# flickr gem rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flickr

In your opinion, what's the best gem for the Flickr API compatible with Rails 3 ?

I just need some basic functions to retrieve some photos based on web page urls for a given size.

Thank you,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just started using the [flickraw](http://rubygems.org/gems/flickraw) gem and it's fantastically simple and worked with little to no trouble. The syntax is identical (or very close to) the flickr API, and I had no problems with the shared secret authentication, using the example provided in the docs.